# css grid overlapping item covering up scrollbar

Tags: css, css-grid

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/dereklin/0tLf05sr/12/

I want to place the expand-handle to the right but just before the scrollbar:

```
  #expand-handle {
    grid-row: 6 / 7;
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    justify-self: end;
    width: 40px;
    height: 140px;
    background-color: #00677f;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 85px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

However, this doesn't work

What is the correct way to do this in css grid?

(margin-right is not the solution I am looking for because I have other pages that might not have the scrollbar)

Comment: Yeah, it's a tricky problem. I understand you don't want to use `margin-right` because you may have other pages without a scrollbar. You also have to consider that scrollbar widths vary among browsers.

Comment: The issue is that the scroll track is included in the layout. It's actually in the column. I would suggest you use one of the other three edges for the expand button (where a scrollbar will never appear), or devise another overall solution.

Comment: The users want the sidebar on the right.  I might just need to use margin-right to hack it for now.  I hope the css-grid spec will address this in the future.

Comment: I don't believe this is a Grid-specific problem. You may encounter similar behavior across CSS. Also, note what I said about scroll track widths. They vary across browsers. `margin-right` won't work (precisely) across browsers.

Comment: When the content overflows, the scrollbar shows up, the right edge of the content moved to the left a bit.  When I overlap an element over the content, the overlapping right edge should follow the content.  I am hoping this could be addressed at some point.  Yeah, the hack won't be 100%.  To be more precise, I probably have to define the grid with small columns and rows and somehow place the handle inside of the cells and use position absolute to lock the handle in place

Comment: The problem, which I've seen before in multiple CSS scenarios, and which is unfortunate, is that the scrollbar exists inside the container (along with the content). The are many posts on SO where attempts are made to "externalize" the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

How about moving `#expand-handle` within `<div class="content"></div>`?

https://jsfiddle.net/pratie/0tLf05sr/23/

Answer (score 0):

Put your **#expand-handle** in your **.main** div.

```
<div class="main">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur .........

    <div id="expand-handle">Expand Me</div>
</div>
```

Then, change your main and expand-handle css like this.

```
    .main {
      grid-area: main;
      height: 1000px;
      position: relative;
    }

      #expand-handle {
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        width: 40px;
        height: 140px;
        background-color: #00677f;
        color: white;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 5px 0px;
        writing-mode: vertical-lr;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-top: 85px;
        text-align: center;
      }
```

Also, remove the overcss in your content and body.

```
    .content {
      /*overflow: auto;*/
    }

   body {
      /*overflow: hidden;*/
    }
```

Comment: do you mean like this?: https://jsfiddle.net/pratie/0tLf05sr/15/  The problem with this is that the handle is no longer sticky

Comment: I see. Sorry about that, I edited my answer.
Hope it would help